Solution to $t u u_t + x u u_x = - t x$ using the method of characteristics
I am reading through J. David Logan's "Applied Partial Differential Equations", and came across the following exercise after reading about the method of characteristics to solve advection equations:
Solve the PDE $t u u_t + x u u_x = - t x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}, t>1$, subject to the initial condition $u(x,1) = f(x)$. (This is exercise 6e in section 1.2)
I tried solving this problem and got an answer which satisfies the PDE, but my solution is ill-defined and I don't know what to do. I'll explain my steps below.
First, divide by $t u$ (dividing by $t$ is certainly justified as $t>1$, but I suspect I might be causing trouble by dividing by $u$?) to get
$$u_t + \frac{x}{t} u_x = - \frac{x}{u}$$
Our characteristic $\xi(x,t)$ will be the integral curve of the equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{x}{t}$. This has solution $x= C t \implies \frac{x}{t} = C$, so setting $\xi = \frac{x}{t}, \tau = t$, the operator $\partial_t + \frac{x}{t}\partial_x$ becomes simply $\partial_\tau$.
$\xi = \frac{x}{t}$ implies $x = \xi t = \xi \tau$, so with $U(\xi,\tau) \equiv u(x,t)$, we have the transformed equation
$$U_\tau = \frac{- \xi \tau}{U}$$
Separating variables and integrating, we find $U^2/2 = -\xi \tau^2/2 + g(\xi)$, or $U(\xi,\tau) = \sqrt{g(\xi)-\xi \tau^2}$. Transforming back to $x-t$ coordinates, $u(x,t) = \sqrt{g(\frac{x}{t})-xt}$. The initial conditions mean that $g(x) = f(x)^2 + x$, so our final solution reads
$$
u(x,t) = \sqrt{f\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)^2 - x \left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)} \tag{*}
$$
Plugging (*) into Mathematica, it shows that this does solve the PDE. However, the problem here is clear: as $t$ increases, $t-\frac{1}{t}$ decreases without bound, while $f(x/t)$ approaches $f(0)$, which is bounded. Therefore, this solution cannot exist for all time. Furthermore, for many functions, it cannot exist for any time $t>1$.
Does this mean the PDE was ill-posed? Can we derive an expression for the "breaking time" $t_b \geq 1$ where the solution stops being real?
Thank you!

Without knowing what kind of function $f(x)$ is , one cannot say that $f(0)$ is bounded. Moreover for some functions $f(x)$ the square root might be not real for every $x$. I think that one cannot go further without more information about $f(x)$.
